# TicTacToe game, asking user to be X or O and infinite loop

Tags: java, string, while-loop, character

Hey I am trying to create a tictactoe game using java and I am having some trouble. This method is supposed to ask the user to select X or O, if the user enters x or o it should be capitalized, anything else is supposed to be rejected and the question repeated. When the program is run it is getting stuck in this while loop, even when entering X/x/O/o. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
public char getPlayerChar() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to be X or O -> ");
    String y = in.nextLine();
    char t = y.charAt(0);
    char tUp = Character.toUpperCase(t);

    while(tUp != 'X' || tUp != 'O') {
        System.out.println("Your market must be an X or an O");
        System.out.println("Please enter an X or an O ->");
        y = in.nextLine();
        t = y.charAt(0);
        tUp = Character.toUpperCase(t);        
    }
    return tUp;
}
```

Comment: Don't compare Strings with `==`. You could take the first character and compare it using `==`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using
while (!(y.equals("X") || y.equals("O") || y.equals("x") || y
                .equals("o"))) {

see the documentation for the  diff between == and equals()  :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it, I'll look into that, didn't know there was a difference.